# MySQL - Getting summary of multiple grouped rows?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

2 tables: owners & cars

An owner can have many cars. A car can be marked as usable_offroad, usable_onroad, or both.   The cars table has usable offroad and usable_onroad fields which can be set to 0 or 1 (no or yes)

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM owners
LEFT JOIN cars on cars.owner_id = owners.id
GROUP BY owners.id
ORDER BY owners.last_name
```

My goal is to return a list of owners, and whether or not each owns a an onroad or offroad vehicle, or both:

```
    Last Name    First Name    Has Offroad Car      Has Onroad Car
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Smith        Todd          Yes                   No
    Smith        Tom           Yes                   Yes
    Test         Sue           No                    Yes
    Thumb        Joe           No                    No
    White        Al            Yes                   No
```

How do I query this? Was thinking of using ROLLUP, but would prefer if the summary wasn't an appended row but an actual field on the already grouped owner row instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    T1.lastname,
    T1.firstname,
    T1.id in (SELECT owner_id FROM cars WHERE usable_offroad) AS `Has Offroad Car`,
    T1.id in (SELECT owner_id FROM cars WHERE usable_onroad) AS `Has Onroad Car`
FROM owners T1
ORDER BY T1.lastname, T1.firstname
```

Results:

```
'Smith', 'Todd', 1, 0
'Smith', 'Tom', 1, 1
'Test', 'Sue', 0, 1
'Thumb', 'Joe', 0, 0
'White', 'Al', 1, 0
```

Here's my test data:

```
CREATE TABLE owners (id INT NOT NULL, firstname NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, lastname NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO owners (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES
(1, 'Todd', 'Smith'),
(2, 'Tom', 'Smith'),
(3, 'Sue', 'Test'),
(4, 'Joe', 'Thumb'),
(5, 'Al', 'White');

CREATE TABLE cars (id INT NOT NULL, owner_id INT NOT NULL, usable_onroad INT NOT NULL, usable_offroad INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO cars (id, owner_id, usable_offroad, usable_onroad) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 0),
(2, 2, 1, 0),
(3, 2, 0, 1),
(4, 3, 0, 1),
(5, 3, 0, 1),
(6, 5, 1, 0);
```

Comment: @k00k: Wasn't me, but I've never seen the `id IN (SELECT ... ` syntax.  Minor, but based on the OP - there's no `is_offroad` column and there's no evaluation on the column either.

Comment: Clarification: `id IN (SELECT` in the SELECT clause.  As is, this would not return yes or no depending on the value.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I think the presentation is best left to the client. Easy to fix though if necessary.

Comment: This ended up working well for me as I already had the presentation layer handling the eval.

Comment: @Mark Byers: I agree, but every so often you find others who aren't so forgiving.  Still, when requirements are clearly defined I admit they have cause.  I see you corrected the column references.

Comment: @OMGPonies: Yes, the wrong column names was a mistake so I fixed that. The return 0 and 1 instead of "Yes" / "No" was a deliberate choice.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT
          o.lastname,
          o.firstname,
          CASE WHEN COALESCE(y.num_offroad, 0) > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS "Has Offroad Car"
          CASE WHEN COALESCE(x.num_onroad, 0) > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS "Has Onroad Car"
     FROM OWNERS o
LEFT JOIN (SELECT c.owner_id,
                  COUNT(*) AS num_onroad
             FROM CARS c
            WHERE c.usable_onroad = 1
         GROUP BY c.owner_id) x ON x.owner_id = o.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT c.owner_id,
                  COUNT(*) AS num_offroad
             FROM CARS c
            WHERE c.usable_offroad = 1
         GROUP BY c.owner_id) y ON y.owner_id = o.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a sub-query to sum all the flags, and then checking if one is `> 1` should do the job:

```
SELECT last_name, first_name,
       CASE WHEN usable_offroad_count > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END has_offroad_car,
       CASE WHEN usable_onroad_count > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END has_onroad_car
FROM (
    SELECT owners.last_name, owners.first_name,
           SUM( cars.usable_offroad ) usable_offroad_count,
           SUM( cars.usable_onroad ) usable_onroad_count
    FROM owners
    LEFT JOIN cars on cars.owner_id = owners.id
    GROUP BY owners.id
)
ORDER BY last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * ,
if ( cars.usable offroad = 1 and  usable_onroad= 1 , 'Both' 
     , if( cars.usable offroad = 1 and  usable_onroad= 0  , 'Offroad' , 'Onroad')
   )  as Status
FROM owners
LEFT JOIN cars on cars.owner_id = owners.id
GROUP BY owners.id
ORDER BY owners.last_name
```